# get.all.shortest.paths help file on $nrgeo

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to find the number of occurences of a specific vertex on all of the shortest paths between given two vertices. For this, I'm using the igraph package in R. I've been using get.all.shortest.paths() on the following graph

```
g <- graph(c(1,2,1,3,2,4,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,6,6,7), directed = F)
```

The problem I get is when I run `get.all.shortest.paths(g,2,3)` I get:

```
$res
$res[[1]]
+ 3/7 vertices:
[1] 2 4 3

$res[[2]]
+ 3/7 vertices:
[1] 2 1 3

$nrgeo
[1] 1 1 2 1 0 1 0
```

which  I assume $nrgeo is the number of occurences of the vertices in all of the shortest paths from vertex 2 to 3. (I couldn't find the help file for the function, so I'm not sure what $nrgeo exactly is.)

However, no shortest path between vertex 2 and vertex 3 contains the vertex 6, and vertex 2 is realized twice, not once.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe nrgeo is the resultant vector of values from [Djikstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) which is used to find the shortest paths.  This will not tell you how many shortest paths a certain vertex lies on between 2 and 3.  Instead you could use something like

```
vertex=1
sum(sapply(get.all.shortest.paths(g,2,3)$res,function(x){vertex %in% x}))
```

to find, for example, the number of shortest paths that vertex 1 lies on.

Comment: Thanks alot, that's exactly what I wanted!